# jqXHR.statusText 'abort' vs 'canceled' when aborting the XHR

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, jqxhr

The [`jqXHR`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object used by `jQuery.ajax` has a property `statusText`, which can have two values when aborting the XHR: `canceled` and `abort`. When is the former used and when is the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the relevant source code of [ajax.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.12-stable/src/ajax.js#L447):

```
        // Default abort message
        strAbort = "canceled",

        // Fake xhr
        jqXHR = {

            ...

            // Cancel the request
            abort: function( statusText ) {
                var finalText = statusText || strAbort;
                if ( transport ) {
                    transport.abort( finalText );
                }
                done( 0, finalText );
                return this;
            }
        };

        ...

        // Apply prefilters
        inspectPrefiltersOrTransports( prefilters, s, options, jqXHR );

        // If request was aborted inside a prefilter, stop there
        if ( state === 2 ) {
            return jqXHR;
        }

        ...

        // aborting is no longer a cancellation
        strAbort = "abort";
```

It reads that if you abort the XHR request in the prefilter, then the `statusText` is `canceled`, otherwise it is `abort`.

Comment: hmm... Does that include the beforeSend callback? I would expect it to be "canceled" if it was aborted before any request was actually sent.

Comment: @KevinB No, the `canceled` status is returned when you use [jQuery.ajaxPrefilter](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/), `abort` is returned when you use `beforeSend`.